# How to filter table with rowspan?

Tags: javascript

So I'm loading data using my API like this:

```
            {% for patient_name, patient_data in patients.items() %}
                {% set rowspan = patient_data.tests|length %}
                {% for test in patient_data.tests %}
                    <tr >
                        {% if loop.first %}
                            <td rowspan="{{ rowspan }}">{{ patient_name }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td>{{ test.patientid }}</td>
                        <td>{{ test.labid }}</td>
                        <td>{{ test.patientsex }}</td>
                        <td>{{ test.patientage }}</td>
                        {% if test.patientage == 15 %}

                        <td>

      </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

That's working fine, and this is how the output looks like:

[image]

I want to add a filter function, so I did this:

```
<script>
        function filterTable() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("filterInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            table = document.getElementById("report-table");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            
            for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; // Adjust the index to match the column you want to filter by
                if (td) {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And this is the output:

[image]

As you can see here, instead of showing two rows just like the first image, because patient A have two tests, it's only showing one row. What's a good way to handle this?

Comment: if possible provide markup and test data